# vector's destructor is called immediately and causes double free or corruption (out)

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function in which vector's destructor is called immediately and causes error. I saw this with QtCreator's debugger

[image]

But when I comment out the next line, it works (not as expected but at least dont give error).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class Solution {
private:
    int min_cost(const std::vector<int>& costs, std::vector<int>& map, int start) const
    {
        //        if (map[start] > -1)
        //            return map[start];

        const int s = costs.size();
        if (start >= s - 2)
            return costs[start];

        int c1 = min_cost(costs, map, start + 1);
        int c2 = min_cost(costs, map, start + 2);

        int cost = std::min(c1, c2);

        if (start > -1)
            cost += costs[start];

        map[start] = cost;
        return cost;
    }

public:
    int minCostClimbingStairs(const std::vector<int>& costs) const
    {
        std::vector<int> map(costs.size(), -1); // from debuder, std::vector<int>::~vector is called here
        return min_cost(costs, map, -1); // commeting out this line out dont gives error
    }
};

int main()
{
    const std::vector<std::vector<int>> input = {
        { 10, 15 },
        { 10, 15, 20 },
        { 1, 100, 1, 1, 1, 100, 1, 1, 100, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    const Solution Sol;

    for (auto const& i : input) {
        std::cout << ' ' << Sol.minCostClimbingStairs(i) << '\n';
    }
}
```

But **How the min function can affect the vector's destructor?** here is [fiddle](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/EWz8H7f)
I tested code with g++ 10.1.0 and clang++ 10.0.0

Comment: @M.M But that error is in min function. why I am getting an error at vector,s initialization ?

Comment: Technically speaking, undefined behaviour can manifest itself _at any time_ or even not at all. A lot of cases mainly depend on compiler optimizations that assume it doesn't happen. Other cases (perhaps this one; to my understanding, it's not uncommon for allocation metadata to be stored immediately before the allocated memory) depend mainly on how the OS responds to doing bad things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program causes undefined behaviour:

```
map[start] = cost;
```

is executed when `start` is `-1`, which accesses out of bounds of the vector.

---

Also you are misinterpreting the debugger output.  The order of operations for the `minCostClimbingStairs` function is:

- Create `map`
- Call `min_cost`
- Destroy `map`
- Return

The first two things happen and then during the destruction of `map`, the heap corruption caused by the out-of-bounds write shows up as a runtime error when trying to destroy it.

If you step through the program line by line you should be able to follow this flow. I guess you ran the program in debugger without stepping and waited for it to stop, but didn't realize that the stop came after the call to `min_cost`. The stack trace output shows the current state of the stack, and `min_cost` does not appear in it since that function has already returned.